# Automatically trust reverse-proxy traffic with custom root CA inside of unmanaged docker containers

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate, zscaler

Is it possible to run publicly available containers as-is when running reverse proxies that sign traffic with a custom root CA?

Example: Zscaler internet security

Corporate environments often run proxies.

While it is possible to install a custom root CA certificate file into a custom-built docker image and successfully run the container (e.g. `COPY ... custom certificate ...` and `RUN ... install custom certificate ...`) and it is also possible to mount the certificate into a container and then run a custom "entrypoint" command to install the certificate, it does not seem possible to simply tell Docker to trust what the host trusts.

For example, when Zscaler signs responses with their root CA, docker container network requests will fail to validate the response, because they do not recognize the Zscaler root CA.

Scenario:

1. Run a public docker image on a Windows computer with Zscaler Client installed
2. When the container starts, if it makes network requests, they are routed through Zscaler
3. Most and perhaps all network requests will fail to process the response, because the container OS and the tools do not trust the Zscaler certificate

This problem is highlighted when tools like Docker Compose or Kubernetes Helm attempt to run multiple containers at a time and many of them require network (of course).

In the distant future, it might be possible to use something like OCI hooks.